# I'm getting error after upgrading to Material UI 4 - withStyles

Tags: reactjs, migration, material-ui

I'm getting the following error after upgrading to MUI v4.0.2 from v3.9.x:

> You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"propTypes":{},"displayName":"WithStyles(MyComponent)","options":{"defaultTheme":{"breakpoints":{"keys":["xs","sm","md","lg","xl"],"values":
>    ...

MyComponent:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const getStyles = theme => ({
  fooBar: {
    ...
  },
})

...
export default withStyles(getStyles)(MyComponent)
```

MyContainer:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

How to migrate `withStyles`?

Comment: What version of react-redux are you using? I think this is related to https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/914 and I believe should be fixed if you are using version 6 or 7 of react-redux.

Comment: @RyanCogswell This has fixed the issue! After upgrading `react-redux` from 5.x to 7.0 the issue is gone! Please write an answer so that I can accept it and future people will know the solution instantly. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Version 5.0.7 and earlier of react-redux performed the following validation on the component passed to `connect`:

https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.0.7/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L91

```
    invariant(
      typeof WrappedComponent == 'function',
      `You must pass a component to the function returned by ` +
      `${methodName}. Instead received ${JSON.stringify(WrappedComponent)}`
    )
```

With the introduction of `React.forwardRef` (which is used heavily in Material-UI v4) and other features introduced in React 16.8 (hooks), it is possible to have a component type that is **not** a function.

More recent versions of react-redux instead use [isValidElementType](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/shared/isValidElementType.js) from the `react-is` package. This correctly recognizes the component types returned by `forwardRef` and other methods.

I believe versions 5.1 and later of react-redux should all work fine without erroneously causing the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I do it:

`import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

Define your styles object: look at the material-ui examples for guidance

```
const styles => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  }
});
```

Then export the component using your styles:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: It worked before upgrading to v4. **What is the difference?** Also, your `const styles => ...` syntax looks invalid.

Comment: Your code seems to have changed. I use a container to connect my component. Perhaps that is the issue?

Comment: I have added the function `getStyles` to avoid confusion.