# I'm upgrade material-ui to v4, It doesn't work properly and throw errors, What caused it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When I upgrade v4, I get errors:

`Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"propTypes":{},"displayName":"WithStyles(EditDialog)",...}`

I tried to view the version of react-redux according to the [I'm getting error after upgrading to Material UI 4 - withStyles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448807/im-getting-error-after-upgrading-to-material-ui-4-withstyles) method:

```
$ npm view react-redux version
7.1.0
```

Obviously, our situation is different.

It should be noted that my project is written using class component, so maybe this is the reason?

Is there any way to help me locate the problem?

---

### ----- Apend --------------

I'm use [umi](https://github.com/umijs/umi) framework, And this is my code:

account/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from '@/utils/pageLayout';

...

import DetailDialog from './components/DetailDialog';
import EditDialog from './components/EditDialog';

class Index extends React.Component {
    ...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { list } = state.account;

  return {
    list
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Index));
```

account/components/DetailDialog.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from '@/utils/pageLayout';

...

class DetailDialog extends React.Component {
  ...
}

DetailDialog.propTypes = {
  open: PropTypes.bool,
  ...
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { list } = state.account;

  return {
    list
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(DetailDialog));
```

account/components/EditDialog.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'dva';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from '@/utils/pageLayout';

...

class EditDialog extends React.Component {
  ...
}

EditDialog.propTypes = {
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

EditDialog.defaultProps = {
  open: false,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { list} = state.account;

  return {
    list,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(EditDialog));
```

@/utils/pageLayout.js

```
const styles = theme => ({
  r: {
    height: '100%',
  },
  ...
});

export default styles;
```

Comment: You need to show some code or provide a codepen. This is too little to work with.

Comment: Please show at least the full line of code where EditDialog gets wrapped by `connect`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I added some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are importing `connect` from 'dva'. Unless you are using a beta version, the latest version of dva is 2.4.1 which includes react-redux as a dependency (not a peer dependency) and it is using [`"react-redux": "5.0.7"`](https://github.com/dvajs/dva/blob/dva%402.4.1/packages/dva/package.json#L38). This will then have the exact same problem as the [question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448807/im-getting-error-after-upgrading-to-material-ui-4-withstyles).

This means you probably have two versions of react-redux in play (and likely two versions of redux as well), one included directly in your own package.json and one pulled in by dva.

Your main options would be to upgrade dva to its most recent beta version (currently 2.6.0-beta.12) or import `connect` from react-redux instead of dva.

I don't know anything about dva, so I have no idea what shape the beta is in, but given that it is the 12th beta, I would guess it is pretty close to a stable release.

If you are consistently importing redux/react-redux pieces from dva, then you may want to consider removing react-redux and redux from your own package.json to avoid duplicating them with different versions.