# MaterialUI withStyles: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm getting this *Warning* when I try to use a component that is exported using the `material-ui` `withStyles` feature, like this:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent)
```

and then passing it into the `ReactRouter` like this:

```
import MyComponentfrom './MyComponent'
<Route path="/my-component" component={MyComponent} />
```

Component is being rendered as expected and runs fine, but the warning bothers me.

Can someone explain why am I getting this?

Update 1(warning added):
[image: Warning]

Comment: Could you add the warning

Comment: What version of react-router are you using?

Comment: It is probably a similar problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448807/im-getting-error-after-upgrading-to-material-ui-4-withstyles/56453897#56453897 except with an old version of react-router instead of an old version of react-redux.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using version 4.3.1 or earlier of react-router.

This uses `component: PropTypes.func` in [Route](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.3.1/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L19).

With the introduction of `React.forwardRef` (which is used heavily in Material-UI v4) and other features introduced in React 16.8 (hooks), it is possible to have a component type that is not a function.

Starting with version 4.4 of react-router, it instead uses [isValidElementType](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.4.0/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L83). This correctly recognizes the component types returned by `forwardRef` and other methods.

Related answer: [I'm getting error after upgrading to Material UI 4 - withStyles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56448807/im-getting-error-after-upgrading-to-material-ui-4-withstyles/56453897#56453897)

Comment: You are correct I was using router 4.1.0. But i cannot see anything after 4.3.1 (no 4.4) it goes straight to 5. I'll try this upgrade

Comment: 4.4 exists in Git, but in npm it went from betas of 4.4 directly to 5.0. I would recommend going to the latest version 5.1.2.